# C Define macro with "or" operator confusion

Tags: android, c, makefile, android-ndk, macros

Confused here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r2/arm-wt-22k/lib_src/eas_wtengine.c#168

```
#if !defined(NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL) || defined(_16_BIT_SAMPLES)
```

Seems like on arm it will be defined, see here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r2/arm-wt-22k/Android.bp#121

But all builds have

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r2/arm-wt-22k/Android.bp#66

So it should be true on both arm and other i.e x86_64, right?

It will be only not defined when frist condition is not met and the 2nd, meaning no EAS_NATIVE_KERNEL flag and no _16_BIT_SAMPLES flag?

Comment: When you say defined, you mean true? `!defined(NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL) || defined(_16_BIT_SAMPLES)` will only be false when `NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL` is defined and `_16_BIT_SAMPLES` isn't defined.

Comment: Thx. Yea I meant defined, true, that the block below will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!defined(NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL) || defined(_16_BIT_SAMPLES)` will only be false when `NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL` is defined and `_16_BIT_SAMPLES` isn't defined (when `defined(NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL) && !defined(_16_BIT_SAMPLES)` is true).

| `NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL` | `_16_BIT_SAMPLES` | `!defined(NATIVE_EAS_KERNEL) || defined(_16_BIT_SAMPLES)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Not defined | Not defined | True |
| Not defined | Defined | True |
| Defined | Not defined | False |
| Defined | Defined | True |